# Symfony security.yaml configuration of two different login pages

Tags: symfony, symfony-security

I haven't found a tutorial in the official Symfony documentation, but I'd like to know if it's possible, via the security.yaml file, to configure two separate connections: one for the administrator interface and client connection page, and a second for the player connection page (quiz games, fictitious players created by the administrator).
So for this, I have two different entities which are the "Player" and the "Users" (admin).

I've also created two separate connections (twig and controller) with `symfony console make:auth` .

However, I'm having trouble configuring all this, and errors occur when I log out. Is it possible to have two firewall entries? I think that's where my error is coming from.
Here's what I've done:

```
security:
    providers:
        app_user_provider:
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\User
                property: email
        app_player_provider:
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\Player
                property: email
    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        login_admin:
            pattern: ^/login-admin
            provider: app_user_provider
            custom_authenticator: App\Security\AppAuthenticator
            logout:
                path: app_logout_user
            
        login_player:
            pattern: ^/login
            provider: app_player_provider
            custom_authenticator: App\Security\AppAuthenticatorPlayerAuthenticator
            logout:
                path: app_logout
            user_checker : App\Security\PlayerChecker

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN
        ROLE_CLIENT: ROLE_CLIENT
        ROLE_USER: ROLE_USER

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/, role: PUBLIC_ACCESS }
        - { path: ^/login, role: PUBLIC_ACCESS  }
        - { path: ^/login-admin, role: PUBLIC_ACCESS  }
        - { path: ^/admin, roles: [ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_CLIENT] }
        - { path: ^/stats, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

Thank you in advance for your help ^^

Otherwise, here is the symfony error:

This method can be blank - it will be intercepted by the logout key on your firewall.

I had tested the providers method, but it doesn't work as I'd like. The player can't log in on the user page, whereas the admin can log in on both login pages. This isn't ideal for security, because players could have simple passwords (like the name of a country, for example, for the game) and players could be blocked so that logging in is only possible for the duration of the game, which is about 1 hour.

```
    providers:
        app_user_provider:
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\User
                property: email
        app_player_provider:
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\Player
                property: email
        
        app_provider:
            chain:
                providers: [app_user_provider, app_player_provider]
```

Comment: Just keep it simple and use one authenticator (the default) and have roles to differentiate between different users. Also only use one entity, the User entity. You can check the role of a user in your controllers and twig files.

Comment: A Player can be a User, so you will have one entity  User and have two roles Role_Admin for Admin and Role_User for the player. Be simple. The doc could  help you https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#roles and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W0FhUq-P9zQ

Comment: In my case, the roles method doesn't work. 

The admin creates customer accounts and players for the game. The customer views the details of the player assigned to them. The player simply logs in and takes part in the company-affiliated quiz.

The problem lies in the relationship between users and companies. Currently, each user is linked to a company (customer) associated with a single e-mail used to access information. If I add players to the user entity, how do I manage the relationship between the company email and the player email?

Comment: It is confusing how you're explaining each user type. So, you should have a *role_super_admin*, this is you, make this account manually. From this account you can create *role_company* and *role_player*. Now in your User entity you can create a *OneToMany* relationship called *players* for example. Now if the User is a company role you can add players (User object) to this collection.